# How to display RSS feed in app?

Tags: android, xml, rss

I don't normally whine this much, but this problem is really painful.

I've been searching for an answer since 4 months and I still don't know how to do this. I taught myself Android from square 1, but this is 1 problem I just can't get around my head.

I've asked at least 20 questions on SO, half got down-rated, the other half got no answer.

I've checked at least half a dozen libraries, spent days to try and integrate it in my app, but nothing has ever worked.
These were the most promising ones:
https://github.com/matshofman/Androi...Reader-Library

https://github.com/ahorn/android-rss

Took hours to integrate and I never felt real sorrow until I was unable to get anything to work.

If you know how to integrate an RSS feed in an app, please help me out! It's the one thing that's stopping my app from becoming the best in it's field. I reckon I would retain twice as many users if I could just have this. A working example is all I need. I've never even seen ONE. I don't how the News apps do it, it's practically magic for me.
I just want a Listview that shows the title, on clicking and item the description opens up. The rest I can do myself. Any working example will do.

Please Help.

Comment: This library would work wonders for you: https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't figured it out by now, I have made a simple library for this exact reason. The current ones are outdated and hard to customize. Try this one and let me know if you need help. The readme should walk you through basic set up. 
https://github.com/ShirwaM/Simplistic-RSS

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this new powerful RSS library I wrote:
https://github.com/Pkmmte/PkRSS

It's very easy to use, extremely customizable, and supports most feeds. For example, the following code loads a specific url in the background:

```
  PkRSS.with(this).load(url).async();
```

And then you can get the list of feeds loading in that url:

```
  List<Article> articleList = PkRSS.with(this).get(url);
```

You can then use that ArrayList in your ListView to populate it. Easy, right? :D